# Working with regression in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like that:

```
height  age  gender
 140     10    male
 150     15    male
 160     20    male
 135     12    female
 170     16    female
 180     20    female
```

So far i have manipulate the data like that, predictor or response variable  is height(Y):

```
Y=   140           X= 1     10      1        β=   β0
     150              1     15      1             β1                                                                                           
     160              1     20      1             β2                                                
     135              1     12      0
     170              1     16      0
     180              1     20      0
```

where 1 and 0 in X matrix are male and female,

I want to perform this function in python

Y= β0 +  β1 X + β2 X

β= (XT   x)   XT  Y

where T is transpose .. i don't know how to perform it as i am not familiar with python

Comment: your calculation of the weight matrix is incomplete. you need to invert the SSCP matrix, so it should be `(XTX)-1 XTY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have numpy installed try this:

```
import numpy as np

#Create a list for Y
y = [140,150,160,135,170,180]

#Convert to numpy array
Y = np.asarray(y).reshape(6,1)

#Create a list for X
x = [[1,10,1],[1,15,1],[1,20,1],[1,12,1],[1,16,1],[1,20,1]]

#Convert to numpy array
X = np.asarray(x).reshape(6,3)

#Multiply using np.matmul for matrix multiplication
beta = np.matmul(np.matmul(np.matmul(X.T,X),X.T),Y)
```

Otherwise, prior to running the above lines of code on the python interpreter, install numpy using your Python package manager. The equivalent command for pip is:

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

Comment: not showing anything??does print statement is needed?

Comment: Yes, if you are not running on the interpreter, add a print statement: print(beta)

Comment: Instead of `np.matmul` you can use `@` according to [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/)